# UE4 get all players in FoV

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I'm trying to build an array of all player pawns that are in the players FoV cone. I'd prefer to not have to loop through GetAllActorsofClass for obvious performance reasons. This will be done every tick.

Comment: So you want to check what player's are in the view of the player currently? I think that there are a couple of ways to do this, from [collision filtering](https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/blog/collision-filtering) to using the dot product or a collider to do some collision detection. 

This will definitely be a rather expensive thing to do, but I don't think you need to use `GetAllActorsOfClass`

Comment: Not technically "viewable". They could be occluded or even render culled.

Visualize a frustum as a volume that extends out to say 800m. Any pawn in the extent would be returned in the result.

Answer (score 0):

GetAllActorsOfClass iterates over a hash table of things of that class. Even with 100 players it is unlikely to be very costly. I would imagine that a "get actors in frustum" would just do that under the hood.

If you are okay with using it, from there you would use ConvertWorldLocationToScreenLocation and compare that to the screen bounds coordinates with GetViewportSize.

The only method the wouldn't use GetAllActorsOfClass I can think of offhand is to calculate the size of the rectangle at the "end" of the frustum, using a giant multi box trace, and filtering based on the dot product. Traces are cheap, dot product is cheap. Whether or not it's cheaper than GetAllActorsOfClass is going to be specific to your game.

If performance is really a problem the best solution is to use code. Depending on your implementation you might be able to use Blueprint nativization to get an extra boost without digging into code.

Answer (score 0):

Use MultiSphereTrace from your player to his FOV direction and loop through hit results.

Make sure you set the collision layer correctly so the trace only interact with target player.

I do this on my mobile game with around 10-20 actors per frame, and it works fine.